# Foreach the results of an API call in php

Tags: php, api, loops, foreach

I have made a GET call through an API and received data that originally looked like this:

```
{"@odata.context":"API-URL-CALL","value":[{"Id":1,"Name":Bill"},{"Id":2,"Name":Ted"}]
```

I took this data and altered it to look like this:

```
array("Id"=>1,"Name"=>"Bill","Id"=>2,"Name"=>"Ted");
```

What I am trying to do is echo this all out but so far I have only been able to get the second Id and Name to print out.

My code is as follows:

```
<?php
$my_array = array("Id"=>1,"Name"=>"Bill","Id"=>2,"Name"=>"Ted");

foreach($my_array as $key => $value)
{
echo 
"
$key = $value <br>
";
}
?>
```

As stated above this only prints out:

```
Id = 2
Name = Ted
```

I feel like this is a simple fix and I have looked at many posts but can't seem t find the proper fix for this. I have tried things such as:

```
$key = $value[0] <br>

$key = $value[0][Id] <br>

foreach($my_array as $arr)
echo 
"
id = $arr[Id], <br>
name = $arr[Name]
"

foreach($my_array as $arr)
echo 
"
id = $arr[0][Id], <br>
name = $arr[0][Name]
"
```

All these ever get me are a single character or nothing at all. Like I said before I feel like this is a simple fix and I'm overlooking something or not adding something? Any help or advise or even a link to another post would be much appreciated. Thank you for your time :^D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how you achieved your second array from the initial JSON (although that has a few errors in the format), but you have flattened the array into a single array which has duplicate keys (and will only end up with the last value).

If you try

```
print_r(array("Id"=>1,"Name"=>"Bill","Id"=>2,"Name"=>"Ted"));
```

you would see the data ends up as

```
Array
(
    [Id] => 2
    [Name] => Ted
)
```

To extract the data properly, you need to decode the JSON (corrected JSON in the code) and then extract the data...

```
$json = '{
    "@odata.context": "API-URL-CALL",
    "value": [
        {
            "Id": 1,
            "Name": "Bill "
        }, 
        {
            "Id": 2,
            "Name": "Ted"
        }
    ]
}';

$my_array = json_decode($json, true);
foreach ( $my_array['value'] as  $arr) {
    echo "
    id = $arr[Id], <br>
    name = $arr[Name]
    ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put quotes around index names.

```
foreach($my_array as $arr)
  echo '
id = '.$arr['Id'].', <br>
name = '.$arr['Name'].'
  ';
```

Comment: I tried that before and it never works, in this case I get the results:

Comment: id = ,
name = ,
id = T,
name = T,

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you defined associative array. This type of array use key=>value pairs. In this type of array keys should be unique.

Because you used none unique keys for example `Id` and `Name`, Every time you insert a value to array it overwrite previous values. So every time you loop through array it just shows last overwrote value.

To fix the problem you should use array inside array:

```
$my_array = array(array("Id"=>1,"Name"=>"Bill"),array("Id"=>2,"Name"=>"Ted"));

foreach($my_array as $array)
{
   echo "{$array['Id']} = {$array['Name']} <br>";
}
```